# Parsing char array

Tags: c, char

I've got a char array as follows:

```
char* test = "+IPD,308:{data:\"abc\"} UNLINK";
```

I'm trying to parse it to return the chunk from `{` to `}`, so in this case the substring `{data:\"abc\"}`.

I've used `strchr()` and `strrchr()` which return a pointer to the location of a single character; but how would I use this to return `{data:\"abc\"}` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const char* input = "+IPD,308:{data:\"abc\"} UNLINK";
char* start = strchr(input, '{');           // result should be input[9]
char* end = strrchr(input, '}');            // result should be input[20]

char* output = (char*)malloc(end-start+2);  // End-start should be 11 + 2 = 13
strncpy(output, start, end-start+1);        // Copy 12 chars.
output[end-start+1] = '\0';                 // Append an End-of-String nul

/* Use the output string.... */

free(output);                               // Very important cleanup!
output = NULL;
```

It finds the first brace, the final brace, allocates appropriate memory, and does a `strncpy` to make a new string with the relevant data.

IDE Link: http://ideone.com/sVn147

Output: `{data:"abc"}`

Comment: You might want to add a check to make sure you don't walk past the null character at the end of the string.

Comment: Also, doesn't this iterate through the string more than once?

Comment: @TrippKinetics: Why is that a problem? He said he wanted to use those functions, and the string is short.

Comment: I get the following complier error : error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive] which points to the line char* output = malloc(endd-start+2);

Comment: @JackTrowbridge: fixed with a typecast on malloc.

Comment: It works! however I get the following result, {data:"abc"}*****************************

Comment: fixed by adding a nul-terminator.

Comment: I've updated my input to : const char* input = "+IPD,308:{data:\"abc\"} UNLINK \0"; However I still get the same result

Comment: It works! I was reading the code wrong, thank you I've been looking for something like this all night!

Comment: NOTE:  Because this allocates the `output` string, you ***must*** call `free(output);` when you are done using it.

Comment: Wouldn't a NULL check be safer after the str-searches? Could a check be necessary to assert `{` < `}`? Defensive programming -- always assume errors may pop up any time. (They still will, but at least you can catch the more obvious cases.)

Comment: My purpose is to answer the question.  It is up to OP to check all errors and make the code bulletproof.

Comment: The code works great, can I ask why do you allocate memory using malloc rather then just set char* output = strncpy(output, start, end-start+1);? I'm a java developer and new to these C concepts

Comment: Its a fair question, but far too involved to answer in a comment.  Short-version: in C, you must manage your own memory, nothing is automatically created/allocated/destroyed for you (unlike Java).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate through the string.  When you reach the first token, start copying characters into a second buffer.  Break out of the loop when you reach the second token.

Comment: You won't know how big to make the second buffer until you've iterated through it.

Comment: @abelenky: you know the theoretical maximum length though: the original string length. With relatively short strings, that would work. (You'd still need to find the original string length. Seems you have to count at least once.)